# EF doesn't updated related entities, only simple fields

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, mapping

I use codeFirst and independent assosiations in EF 6.1
EF doesn't wont to update detached entities. Attach and StateModified doesn't help for Related(FK) entities. 
Adding new Entities and upadting non related properties works correctly.
Where is the problem?

I have main entity CoachTransaction  :

```
public class CoachTransaction : BaseEntity
    {
        public DateTime? TransactionDate { get; set; }

        public int? Season { get; set; }
        public virtual CoachPosition Position { get; set; }
        public virtual Institution StartInstitution { get; set; }
        public virtual Institution EndInstitution { get; set; }       
    }
```

Mapping for it:

```
public MapCoachTransaction()
        {
            ToTable("CoachTransactions");
            HasKey(x => x.Id);

            Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("TransactionId");
            Property(x => x.TransactionDate);

            HasOptional(x => x.Position).WithMany().Map(x => x.MapKey("CoachPositionId"));
            HasOptional(x => x.StartInstitution).WithMany().Map(x => x.MapKey("StartInstitutionId"));
            HasOptional(x => x.EndInstitution).WithMany().Map(x => x.MapKey("EndInstitutionId"));
        }
```

Related Entities looks like this:

```
 public class Institution : BaseEntity
    {
        public virtual InstitutionType InstitutionType { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }        
    }
```

Mapping for Related entities:

```
 public MapInstitution()
        {
            ToTable("Institution");
            HasKey(x => x.Id);
            Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("InstitutionId");
            HasOptional(x => x.InstitutionType).WithMany(x => x.Institutions).Map(x => x.MapKey("InstitutionTypeId"));
            Property(x => x.Name).HasColumnName("InstitutionName");
            Property(x => x.ImageUrl).HasColumnName("InstitutionImageUrl");
        }
```

The usage is like this:

```
                using (var context = new CoachDBContext())
                {
                    IGenericRepository<CoachTransaction> repository = new GenericRepository<CoachTransaction>(context);
                   coachTransaction.Seasion = 100; // this works
                    coachTransaction.EndInstitution = newInstitution; this doesnt'
                    repository.Update(coachTransaction); // coachTransaction comes from POST to Controller
                    repository.Save();
                }
```

and repository.Updarte method ofcourse uses Attach:

```
public virtual void Update(TEntity entityToUpdate)
        {
            EntitySet.Attach(entityToUpdate);
            dbContext.Entry(entityToUpdate).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
```

With this settings the SQL request looks like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[CoachTransactions]
SET [TransactionDate] = @0, [Season] = @1
WHERE ([TransactionId] = @2)
',N'@0 datetime2(7),@1 int,@2 int',@0='2015-04-21 20:40:38.1840996',@1=100,@2=24
```

So, there is no my endInstitution entity to be updated.

But if I request this entity before save:

```
  using (var context = new CoachDBContext())
                    {
                        IGenericRepository<CoachTransaction> repository = new GenericRepository<CoachTransaction>(context);
                        var coachTransaction = repository.GetById(coachTransaction.Id) // this fixes problem, but not acceptable in this case
                        coachTransaction.Season = 100; 
                        coachTransaction.EndInstitution = newInstitution; // now this will work
                        repository.Update(coachTransaction); // coachTransaction comes from POST to Controller
                        repository.Save();
                    }
```

And SQL will contain Related keys like :

```
exec sp_executesql N'UPDATE [dbo].[CoachTransactions]
SET [TransactionDate] = @0, [Season] = @1, 

[EndInstitution] = @2

WHERE ([TransactionId] = @3)
',N'@0 datetime2(7),@1 int,@2 int, @3 int',@0='2015-04-21 20:40:38.1840996',@1=100,@2=2,@3=24
```

**P.S.**

Also, usage of Foreignkey assosiation approeach fixes this problem with mappting like this:

```
Property(x => x.PositionId).HasColumnName("CoachPositionId");
            Property(x => x.StartInstitutionId).HasColumnName("StartInstitutionId");
            Property(x => x.EndInstitutionId).HasColumnName("EndInstitutionId");
            HasRequired(x => x.Position).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.PositionId);
            HasRequired(x => x.StartInstitution).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.StartInstitutionId);
            HasRequired(x => x.EndInstitution).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.EndInstitutionId);
```

But it causes another problem, when I have to set two properties instead of one when update Related entity, like:

```
updatingObject.EndInstitution = existingInstitution2; 
updatingObject.EndInstitutionId = existingInstitution2.Id;
```

insead of one call:
    updatingObject.EndInstitution = existingInstitution2;

Also it requires useless Id properties. This looks wrong from my point of view.
Is there some solution?

Comment: Right, you're either going to have to do a SetValues on the child or use GraphDiff. http://blog.maskalik.com/entity-framework/2013/12/23/entity-framework-updating-database-from-detached-objects/

Comment: But how is it possible to have a generic repository which saves and concreate properties which have to be updated with SetValue ?

Comment: So, I tried:
 updatingEntity.EndInstitution = endInstitution;
                repository.Update(updatingEntity);
                dbContext.Entry(updatingEntity.EndInstitution).CurrentValues.SetValues(endInstitution);

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Attach method don't attach sub-entities. In order to do this, you need to Attach all the dependents target that you want to update.
You can use [GraphDiff](https://github.com/refactorthis/GraphDiff) to update a full graph without attaching the entities. The usage is something like this:
using (var con

```
text = new TestDbContext())  
{
    // Update the company and state that the company 'owns' the collection Contacts.
    context.UpdateGraph(company, map => map
        .OwnedCollection(p => p.Contacts, with => with
            .AssociatedCollection(p => p.AdvertisementOptions))
        .OwnedCollection(p => p.Addresses)
    );

    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This is the a [brief introduction](http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/introducing-graphdiff-for-entity-framework-code-first-allowing-automated-updates-of-a-graph-of-detached-entities/) to the framework.

In addition, I have been reviewing the source code of Entity Framework and found a way to actually update an entity if you know the Key property in another case you need to check the AddOrUpdate implementation:

```
public void Update(T item)
{
    var entity = _collection.Find(item.Id);
    if (entity == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    _context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(item);
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: But how is it possible to use this method in generic repository, when the properties (like p.Contacts  in your example) are different?

Comment: This sample is from the DiffGraph introduction. In order to achieve that with a generic repository you need to review the framework OR look for a workaround because EF don't have Update in the way that you need

Comment: Which ORM has better update? Does Nhibernate have? other framework? Because as for me it looks very strange to have version 6 and not to do basic operations

Comment: NHibernate has a classic update. Probably you can goes in that direction